# Map single entity field to multiple dB columns in spring data jpa and postgres sql

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement where I need to map single entity field in the `Entity` class which can be mapped to any of the three columns of the entity table
Ex. `private String value_type` should be mapped to dB columns `value1` or `value2` or `value3` . In these three whichever field is not `null` it will be assigned to `value_type`
How can I achieve this using **spring data jpa** or any annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this just with annotations.

One thing that should work is to have `value1`, `value2`, and `value3` as attributes along with `value_type`. Make `value_type` [`@Transient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) and without a field. Instead, implement logic in its getters and setter to read and write to the `valueX` fields.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any reference for this on how to achieve this?